# error in popover done in react with material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component done in React that has 6 experiences and each experience creates a popover with an array of images. I make the popover using material ui, the popover works but I have a couple of errors in the console and don't know how to fix them.

this is my component

```
const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const experience = (img, title, category, id, popoverCategory, open) => (
      <div
        className="experience"
        aria-describedby={id}
        id={id}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>

        <Popper
          id={id}
          open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
        >
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (
                <img
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  data-src={popoverCategory}
                  alt="Puntospoint"
                />
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );


    return (

      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', 'gastronomia', gastronomiaExperiences, open)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard', 'giftcard', giftcardExperiences, open)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', 'deporte', deporteExperiences, open)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', 'productos', productosExperiences, open)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', 'diversion', diversionExperiences, open)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', 'belleza', bellezaExperiences, open)}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  },
);
```

These are the errors

[image]

this is the first time I use material ui and I am new to react so I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning about unique keys is usually caused by using `Array.map` somewhere and not providing a key to the elements that are produced. In your case it's here:

```
<div className={classes.paper}>
  {
    popoverCategory.map(url => (
      <img
        data-sizes="auto"
        className="lazyload"
        data-src={popoverCategory}
        alt="Puntospoint"
      />
    ))
  }
</div>
```

So you're creating a bunch of `img` tags without keys. It's probably fine to do this in your case, but best practice is to provide keys so that if you remove, add or re-order elements then you won't get unexpected behaviour. The fix is easy:

```
<div className={classes.paper}>
  {
    popoverCategory.map((url, key) => (
      <img
        data-sizes="auto"
        className="lazyload"
        data-src={popoverCategory}
        alt="Puntospoint"
        {...key}
      />
    ))
  }
</div>
```

The second problem is here:

```
 <Popper
   id={id}
   open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id}
   anchorEl={anchorEl}
  >
```

If `anchorEl` is not defined then you are trying to assign `undefined` to `open`, which is disallowed by the propType defined somewhere. It looks like it should be `true` or `false` only - if so, you can fix it in any way that forces the result of the condition to be true or false but not undefined, such as `anchorEl ? anchorEl.id === id : false` or `anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id || false`.

Comment: when i use anchorEl ? anchorEl.id === id : false or anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id || false. In the terminal I get Line 130:48:  Unexpected mix of '&&' and '||'

Answer (score 0):

Official React documentation is a great source of knowledge for beginners - please make use of it (https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

As for the errors.

'key' error: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Basically, each time you define children of the component via iteration over the list of something, as you do here: `popoverCategory.map(url => (`, you need to supply a 'key' attribute that will help React optimize rendering.

'open prop' error: https://material-ui.com/api/popper/

As you can see 'open' is a required property, so Popper component expects you to pass something in it. Because of the way you composed your condition: `anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id`, your 'open' propertyis populated with null, because if `anchorEl` is null then result of the `&&` operator is also null. And your anchorEl is null, because you set it to null, when you initialize it as part of the state of your component.